# Changing permissions on a File from applicationDataDirectory in Titanium Mobile

Tags: file, mobile, titanium, file-permissions

I'm trying to send a file, as an attachment, via the phone's e-mail client using Titanium Mobile. I've run into a snag where the attachment is sent, but is received as a 0-byte file.

The problem is that the file created in `data/data/package/app_appdata` is `-rw------`

From glancing at the Android SDK, this is by design. The app's "private storage" is readable only by the owner of that folder, the running application.
I presume that the Android e-mail client can see that file, but cannot read it.

The full Android SDK mentions a MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE that allows you to keep using the applicationDataDirectory and give all apps permission to read/write that file. Does an equivalent exist in Titanium Mobile?

The other solution is to create a temp file, which unfortunately uses Titanium's own naming scheme (tiXXXXX.txt), or I could write to the "external storage" since it is public (which may not always be available, however.)

This is the call I'm using to get the current file, it can be read within my app just fine, but when I use the `addAttachment` call of an `emailDialog` it simply sends a 0 byte file to me.

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, "generated_filename.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `tempDirectory` instead. I'm of course assuming once the file is emailed you don't need to keep it as the `applicationDataDirectory` is fully backed up and usually used to store data the app retains.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Filesystem.tempDirectory-property.html

Comment: I have tried, it returns a lovely "undefined" when printed out using Ti.API.info(), and in the app it throws an IOException stating that the directory (presumably ./undefined) is read-only.

Funny thing is the Kitchen Sink app also demonstrates tempDirectory by printing it to API.info, and this also returns undefined. I presume it's been deprecated and the API doc has yet to reflect this... similar to how createFile() is still in the API doc but doesn't exist as a function anymore.

Comment: I get `undefined` for the `tempDirectory` in 1.6.* and lower but in 1.7 beta I get a working `tempDirectory`. I've seen features built into KS long before they are available so it might be one of those. I'm away from my device at the moment but I'll attempt to alert the `tempDirectory` on my device at 1.7 and get back to you.

Comment: Ah it seems that `tempDirectory` isn't android compatible yet thus the `undefined`

Comment: Sorry triple post... anyways take a look at this http://pastie.org/1882099 you can see that file's are `writeable` and not `readonly` on iPhone but not on android. I don't see anyway to write to those properties unless you can force it with `file.readonly = 0;` and `file.writable = 1;`?

Comment: From what I've read over on the real Android SDK, the files are intentionally read-only to sandbox them from other apps.

Not positive, but I think that iOS runs most user applications as the "mobile" user, whereas it seems Android creates a user/group per app.

I suppose I'll have to cross my fingers and wait... or just store it to the SD-Card on the Android. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, are your fingers still crossed ?